# Help with XSS Evasion

Tags: xss

I have a form which performs a strange kind of XSS Filtering.

`<script>alert(1);</script>` is converted into `<script>alert%281%29%3B<%2Fscript>`. How do I bypass this kind of XSS evasion?

If possible, I would also love to see the explanation of the solution.

**EDIT** : \n and period have not been escaped.

Form :

`<form method="POST" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="n">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">`

Comment: Are the following characters escaped: `= , & .` and `\n`?

Comment: \n ' and . don't seem to be.  =  , & escaped.

Comment: Can you do `"` or `'`?

Comment: It's hard to say without having the page to test with, but if you cannot close the script tag due to `/` being encoded, and you cannot create attributes due to `=` being encoded, then I don't think you can execute JS. something like <svg onload=alert\`xss?\`> would let you demo it without parens or closing `/`, but you need the equal sign.

Comment: you may refer to OWASP XSS Filtering document  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet this link gives ways we can filter to evade xss attacks